# How good of a conductor is laser-induced graphene from Kapton tape (polyimide)?

Tags: electromagnetism, conductivity, materials, resistivity

I had intentions of making a DC electromagnet using [laser-induced graphene (LIG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene_production_techniques#Laser-Induced_Graphene_(LIG)), where the graphene will be used as a **flexible** electromagnetic coil. Something like those [24V electromagnets](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/32823785770.html?pdp_npi=2%40dis%21USD%21US%20%2411.70%21%249.24%21%21%21%21%21%402101f6b516684425672112647e87f8%2164998372573%21btf&_t=pvid%3A5284920f-d3a3-4d70-8415-87a246eca2d2&afTraceInfo=32823785770__pc__pcBridgePPC__xxxxxx__1668442567&spm=a2g0o.ppclist.product.mainProduct&gatewayAdapt=glo2bra4itemAdapt) you can find online. But I had a concerns on the quality of such a magnet.

Well, I don't know much about electrical engineering in general, so I was trying to find the numbers and compare to other known materials, such as copper.
But unfortunately I couldn't find any precise answer, most of the papers say different values for different conditions.

For example:

- In [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330331142_Laser-Induced_Graphene_on_Additive_Manufacturing_Parts) they say they achieved 15.9Ω/sq, but they've made a interdigital electrode capacitor (whatever this means).
- In [this other paper](https://encyclopedia.pub/entry/25269#:%7E:text=Cardoso%20et%20al.,using%20MIPs%20as%20biometric%20elements.) they say 102.4 ± 7.3 Ω/square, but their objective is completely different, they are trying to make electrochemical biosensors.
- In [this other paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsnano.1c04197), they say they used a treatment to help the LIG to increase its conductivity. But the article is behind a paywall and sci-hub just shows an "404 not found" message, so I can't tell much.
- [This one](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms6714) is about a infrared CO2 laser process (I didn't even knew CO2 lasers could be infrared) and it achieved the conductivity of ~25 S cm−1.
- I just found [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acsaelm.1c00480?cookieSet=1) talking about a low resistivity LIG: 0.30 Ω/sq
  Apparently, the laser's power used is significant to the result, since they used a 30W laser in a "special" substrate of Polyetherimide (PEI) filament; while other papers (like the ones I listed) just used lasers around 4,5 W power on polyimide substrates.

Comparing to copper, the most commonly used metal on cables and electromagnets, which have 16.78 nΩ•m of resistivity and 58 MS/m (both values are in 20 ºC, I don't know if commercially available copper have the same values).

---

**The question:**

I don't know if this means LIG is just plain bad or if the papers **simply aren't good as a reference** because they simply are neither trying to make a conductor, nor an electromagnet.

Taking better sources (or simply taking these sources) is LIG made from Kapton tape a good conductor?

Comment: Depends on what you consider a good conductor. But electromagnets require *very* good conductors, and this isn't nearly good enough for that. It would need to be five or six orders of magnitude better before it would be workable as a material for an electromagnet.

Comment: `I didn't even knew CO2 lasers could be infrared` ... you may be confusing the CO2 laser with some other type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a perfect contiguous sheet of graphene can have an electrical conductivity up to [70% better than copper](https://www.bosch.com/stories/can-graphene-compete-with-copper-in-electrical-conductivity), the problem is that the laser is going to create non-contiguous sheets which will probably be far inferior to pure copper.

Comment: Graphene resistivty is low, yes, but because of its low thickness resistance still is really high.